# Add swipe support to JS slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Task is making slider on native JS and adding swipe support on mobile. Maybe someone know where is a good tutorial for it without jquery and variety frameworks.
https://kahjuksei.github.io/task-slider/index.html

Comment: I know this may be weird, but i would check the https://www.w3schools.com/ and look for javascript refs that may help, such as `touchstart` , `touchend` , `touchcancel` , `touchmove`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own swipe functions with `touchstart` and `touchend` events. (It's not supported on desktop safari right now, but you can use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on desktop).
Just add some eventlisteners to you element and watch the event `pageX` property.

```js
let xPos;
const touchStart = (event) => {
  xPos = event.pageX;
};
const touchEnd = (event) => {
  if (event.pageX < xPos) {
  // you swiped left
  } else {
  // you swiped right
  }
};
window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
window.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
```

Also you can use the `touchmove` event too for more complex and more advanced swipe implementation.