# pageX only in a certain div

Tags: javascript

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462470/10391705) about adding swipe support to a slider helped me to make it work.

```
let xPos;
const touchStart = (event) => {
xPos = event.pageX;
};
const touchEnd = (event) => {
  if (event.pageX < xPos) {
   $('.centered-btns1_nav.next').click();
} else if (event.pageX > xPos) {
   $('.centered-btns1_nav.prev').click();
  }
};
window.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart);
window.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd);
```

It works when swiping but it also works when scrolling down or up the page.

So how can I limit this so that it will only work on the div #slider?

Something like

```
if (event.pageX < xPos) && (document.getElementById('slider'))
```

Comment: `Touch.target` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/target

Comment: What about changing the event listener from `window` to the slider element?

Comment: Hi, @Nora. Thank you very much. Yes, changing `window` to `slider` solved my problem. Much appreciated.